# How to restore a too large backup

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I made a backup of my system using Déjà Dup, and have it stored on an external hard drive. Today the day finally came when I needed it. When I tried to restore all, Déjà Dup timed out. So I tried manually going through all the files and restoring them one at a time. This worked for all files except for `/snap`, `/srv`, `/usr`, and `/var`.

I looked at the folder where the backups were stored and it was > 300GB. My Laptop only has 120GB, so I checked and one of the files to restore was my `/media` folder, to which at the time of backup had a 2TB hard drive connected to it. I suspect this has made the backup too bulky for my tiny laptop to handle. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can restore a single directory by giving commands like:

`deja-dup --restore /directory`

You could get one directory at a time that way, and leave out the media directory,

Comment: I just tried that and left it to run overnight. Sadly it still crashes for those folders

Comment: @LeahWaymire deja-dup isn't really intended for backup of systems folders. Running it with sudo is a bad idea

Comment: I have become painfully aware of that, but I never did run it under sudo